# Create private Gradle task which is not visible on task list

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to create private Gradle task which is not visible on task list (gradlew tasks)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Gradle doesn't support marking a task as "private". However, `gradle tasks` will only show a task if it either has `task.group` set, or no other task depends on it. The idea behind this is that such a task is likely meant to be executed directly by the user. In contrast, `gradle tasks --all` will show all tasks.

Comment: Specifically, this means you can hide default tasks provided by a plugin by setting its group property to null:  unwantedTask.group = null

Comment: @ChristopherBarber, it will not be hidden from list of all groups, by setting null or "" you just move this task to group with name "other".